# Tablet LCD display to hdmi

Tags: lcd, display

I have an old tablet and an old phone and I have recovered the lcd displays from both of them. I want to use them as monitors with an hdmi or vga port, but seeing the cables of the two i do not know where to start and what i need. First i would like to understand why is the connector of the phone display "wider" or has more pins than the tablet one.
Here are some pictures.

Phone cable:
[image]

Tablet cable:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Unless you can find out the schematics or data sheets, there is virtually zero chance of determining what the interface is and how to convert HDMI or VGA to that interface.

Comment: So every device has it's own interface? And if i had the schematics what would i need to do to make it work?

Comment: the tablet connector is wider ... it has 70 pins ...  the phone has only 54

Comment: This has been asked a couple of times already. Search for "phone screen HDMI" on this site.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standardized video interface. Most likely, they are using a parallel protocol for that. If you wished to used those display, you would have quite a lot of reverse engineering to do to figure what each pin does. Maybe you can find a datasheet, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Sadly, there isn't much you can do beyond that. Even if you figure each signals, you still don't have the command list. The LCD controller is probably epoxied, if not, maybe try to find it's datasheet, but you will waste a lot of time. You should just buy an LCD with a proper datasheet.